# How to force Unity's SerializedProperty to call OnValidate callback?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am writing a extension method to simplify the use of [SerializedProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html)

The idea is that the user of the method should be able to set the value of a `SerializedProperty` without having to worry about the type. As illustrated in the example below, the correct type should be handled according the the type of `serializedProperty` and `myValue`.

**Example of the regular use of `SerializedProperty`, the Unity way:**

```cs
serializedProperty.intValue = myIntValue;
serializedProperty.floatValue = myFloatValue;
serializedProperty.boolValue = myBoolValue;
...
```

**Intended syntax for my `SerializedProperty` method extension**

```cs
serializedProperty.SetValue(myValue);
```

**My current implementation of this `SerializedProperty` method extension**

```cs
public static void SetValue<TValue>(this SerializedProperty property, TValue value)
{
    if (property.hasMultipleDifferentValues)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

    Type parentType = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
    FieldInfo fieldInfo = parentType.GetField(property.propertyPath);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(property.serializedObject.targetObject, value);
}
```

---

**The Problem:**

This implementation does not call the `OnValidate` Unity callback. The regular usage (`mySerializedProperty.intValue = myInt`) does.

**MY QUESTION**: Is there any way to force Unity to call the `OnValidate` method on the `SerializedProperty`?

I have considered calling `OnValidate` by myself via reflection but since this is already implemented in Unity I was wondering if there was a way to mark the `SerializedProperty` as changed or something similar.

---

**For testing this behavior, I have written the following test (NUnit):**

```cs
private IntMonoBehaviourMock _mockInstance;

[SetUp]
public void CallBeforeEachTest()
{
    GameObject gameObject = new GameObject();
    this._mockInstance = gameObject.AddComponent<IntMonoBehaviourMock>();
}

[Test]
// This test fails for the current implementation
public void SetValue_ToDifferentValue_OnValidateCalledOnce()
{
    this.SetValueOfSUT(0x1CE1CE);

    int numCallsBefore = this._mockInstance.NumTimesValidateCalled;
    this.SetValueOfSUT(0xBABE);
    int numCallsAfter = this._mockInstance.NumTimesValidateCalled;

    int actualNumCalls = numCallsAfter - numCallsBefore;
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actualNumCalls); // Fails
}

private void SetValueOfSUT(int value)
{
    string fieldName = "publicSerializedField"
    SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this._mockInstance);
    SerializedProperty sut = this._serializedObject.FindProperty(fieldName);

    // This is the call to function being tested!
    // Swapping this for sut.intValue = value, makes the test pass.
    // (But the purpose is to write a function that handles any type correctly)
    sut.SetValue(value);

    this._serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

The implementation of **IntMonoBehaviourMock** that I am using in the test is:

```cs
public class IntMonoBehaviourMock: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int publicSerializedField = default;

    public int NumTimesValidateCalled { get; private set; }

    protected void OnValidate()
    {
        this.NumTimesValidateCalled++;
    }
}
```

The result of the test is:

```
Expected: 1
  But was:  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ofcourse call `OnValidate` also without Reflection by making it

```
public void OnValidate() ...
```

and then in the Editor call

```
theProperty.SetValue(5);
((IntMonoBehaviourMock)target).OnValidate();
```

or what I sometimes do is make the Editor a subclass of the according type so you have access to `private` and `protected` methods as well. I usually male it still in different files using

```
public partial class IntMonoBehaviourMock
{
    ...

#if UnityEditor
    private partial class IntMonoBehaviourMockEditor { }
#endif
}
```

and then in a separate file

```
#if UnityEditor
public partial class IntMonoBehaviourMock
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(IntMonoBehaviourMock)]
    private partial class IntMonoBehaviourMockEditor : Editor
    {
        ...
    }
}
#endif
```

---

The possible types are quite limited

```
AnimationCurve, BoundsInt, bool, Bounds, Color, double, float, int, long, 
Quaternion, RectInt, Rect, string, Vector2, Vector2Int, Vector3, Vector3Int, Vector4
```

and a special one

```
UnityEngine.Object
```

which is the parent class for (almost) all Unity classes.

I can think of alternatively using something like

```
var type = typeof(TValue);

if(type == typeof(int))
{
    serializedProperty.intValue = value;
}
else if(type == typeof(string)
{
    serializedProperty.stringValue = value;
}

...

else if(type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(UnityEngine.Object)))
{
    serializedProperty.objectReferenceValue = value;
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("Unassignable type: " + type.FullName);
}
```

actually you would then not even require the generic but could also simply use

```
var type = value.GetType();
```

Comment: Manually enumerating all possible types indeed works and presents the correct behavior. Thank you so much for your answer - will probably use it. On a side note, the only reason I am not giving you the "accepted answer" right now is because the actual question of "How to force Unity's SerializedProperty to call OnValidate callback?" remains itself unanswered, even though your solution solves the macro problem. Because of that, I will wait a little bit to see if someone comes up with a better answer.

Comment: Additionally, this could be the case of a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)